# For every interval $I$ in $\mathbb R$ , there exists a continuous surjection from $I \setminus \mathbb Q$ to $I \cap \mathbb Q$?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Is it true that for every interval (not singleton ) $I$ in $\mathbb R$ , there exists a continuous surjection  $f : I \setminus \mathbb Q \to I \cap \mathbb Q$ ?

Comment: It can't be a singleton anyway, since if it is a singleton exactly one of $I\cap\Bbb Q$ and $I\setminus\Bbb Q$ is non-empty.

Comment: You should specify the topology you want $f$ to be continuous with respect to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will show it for $I=[0,1]$. Take
$$ f\colon I\setminus \Bbb{Q} \to  I \cap \Bbb{Q} $$
to be the constant function with value $\varphi (n)$ on $[\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n}]$ where $\varphi \colon \Bbb{N} \to \Bbb{Q}\cap I$ is any surjection.

This function is only "discontinuous" at rational points, so $f$ is continuous and by construction $f$ is surjective.

For the general case just fit $[0,1]$ into your favorite interval and extend the function by $0$ on the left and right.

Comment: Right, my mistake, sorry for that.

Comment: Minor pedantic point: you need to make one endpoint or the other of $[1/(n+1),1/n]$ be open so that your $f$ is not ambiguously defined at the $1/n$ points.

Comment: @Ian But $f$ is not defined on rational points anyway.

Comment: Oh, right, yes, I guess it should be $[1/(n+1),1/n] \setminus \mathbb{Q}$ but now that's an even more pedantic point. Sorry.